# The onStop() of activity is not called when activity no longer visible

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

In a normal situation, as per https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onstop, it is indicated

`When your activity is no longer visible to the user, it has entered the Stopped state, and the system invokes the onStop() callback. This may occur, for example, when a newly launched activity covers the entire screen.`

I have an example design below
https://github.com/elye/issue_android_activity_not_stop_when_not_visible

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Log.d("Track", "MainActivity: onStart")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Log.d("Track", "MainActivity: onStop")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.d("Track", "MainActivity: onResume")
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.d("Track", "MainActivity: onPause")
    }

    fun onButtonClicked(view: View) {
        startActivity(Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java))
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        startActivity(Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

In this design, the `MainActivity` will launch `NextActivity`. In normal launch using the Button to click, the `MainActivity` does call `onStop` as it launches the `NextActivity`

To replicate the case where `onStop()` of `MainActivity` is not called when `MainActivity` is not visible anymore, below is the step

1. Open up `MainActivity` (which is `singleTask`)
2. Deeplink through `DeeplinkActivity` (which is `singleInstance`) using

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://www.onstoptrigger.com/test"
```

The `DeeplinkActivity` will trigger the `onNewIntent()` of `MainActivity`. In the `onNewIntent()`, it will launch `NextActivity`.

Here, when `NextActivity` is launched, the `MainActivity` only called `onPause()`. The `MainActivity`'s `onStop()` is not called. Is this expected?

I feel like it's an Android bug but would love to be corrected.

Note:

1. If I change `DeeplinkActivity` to `singleTask`, the problem doesn't occur
2. If I deeplink directly into `MainActivity` (without using `DeeplinkActivity`, the problem doesn't occur too

Comment: Reported an issue to Google on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192969954